# why is my math wrong in Java?

Tags: java

In the following code, I see no way in which T1 and T3 are different.  Certainly my calculator says they are not.

```
public class longTest {
    public static final long T1 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30;
    public static final long T2 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    public static final long T3 = T2 * 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(T1);
        System.out.println(T2);
        System.out.println(T3);
    }
}
```

So why do I get output of:

```
-1702967296
86400000
2592000000
```

It's not just System.out.println in this sample program either.  When I have T1 in eclipse and  mouse over the variable I get a gloss showing the same values.

> java version "1.6.0_33" OSX

Comment: *"is math fundamentally broken in Java?"* -  Of course not!

Comment: @Shark *Integer* overflow. The value doesn't become a long until somebody converts it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As paranoid-android says, it's an `int` overflow issue.  To understand why T3 is different, see below.

```
public static final long T1 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30;
```

All the numbers here are `int`s so this is the same as

```
public static final long T1 = (long) (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30);
```

The `int` part overflows, so the implicit cast to `long` arrives too late to avoid loss of precision.
In

```
public static final long T2 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

you have the same but its a smaller number that fits in both a 32 bit `int` (31 bits for positive values) and in a 64 bit `long`.

```
public static final long T3 = T2 * 30;
```

This multiplies a `long` by an `int` so does 64 bit arithmetic which is why it has a different value.
It's equivalent to

```
public static final long T3 = T2 * (long) 30;
```

The implicit `long` here is early enough to prevent loss of precision.

Answer (score 8):

You're getting overflow because an `int` can't be greater than 2,147,483,647. The final values is not outside of the range of `long` types, but the arithmetic itself treats the numbers as `int` unless you explicitly state that they are `long` values.

Try this:

```
public class LongTest {

    public static final long T1 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30;
    public static final long T2 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    public static final long T3 = T2 * 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(T1);
        System.out.println(T2);
        System.out.println(T3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `L` instead of `l` to indicate `long`.  Lower-case `l` looks awfully like `1` in many terminal fonts whereas `L` does not.

Comment: actually this is fine too public static final long T1 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30;

Answer (score 1):

This is because in `T1`, all of the numbers are Integers, so the math operations are performed on Integers, then assigned to a long. `T3` is multiplying a Long with an Integer, so it uses a Long while doing the math, and the result is as expected.

To fix it, you need to change your number constants to be long:

```
public class longTest {
   public static final long T1 = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L * 30L;
   public static final long T2 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
   public static final long T3 = T2 * 30;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(T1);
      System.out.println(T2);
      System.out.println(T3);
   }

}
```

To understand why you get a negative number: When it gets to the largest positive number (2^31 -1), it wraps around to the largest negative number (-2^31) and goes up from there. This wrapping can occur multiple times, so when you do:

```
public static final int T4 = 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100;// = 1410065408 WHAT!?!?
```

You get 10 billion, which is larger than what an Integer can hold. So, once it gets to 2,147,483,647, it next goes to -2,147,483,648 and so on.. So, for 10 billion it goes something like this:

2,147,483,647 (roll over to negatives, we still have 7,852,516,353 left to go)

-2,147,483,648 (count all the way up to Integer.MAX_INT)

2,147,483,647 (roll over to negatives again, we still have 3,557,549,057 to go)

-2,147,483,648 (add the remaining 3,557,549,058)

And now we have: 1,410,065,408